# Android: Broken functionality after upgrade from API 22 to API 23

Tags: android, api, upgrade

I am using Android Studio 2.1.1.
After upgrading from API 22 to API 23 basic functions that worked before do not work any more.
2 examples:
1) Get list of files returned all files and folders in the specified path in API 22, now in API 23 *files* is null:

```
    File f = new File(dirPath);
    File[] files = f.listFiles();
```

2) Get accounts from device returns all eMail-accounts in API 22, now in API 23 *accounts* is null:

```
    Pattern emailPattern = Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS;
    accounts = AccountManager.get(this).getAccounts();
```

Other examples cannot be described that simply, so I hope giving just the 2 examples is sufficient.
My gradle file for API 22:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion '22.0.1'
    compileOptions.encoding = 'windows-1251'

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    }
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.soft.StudyNJoy"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 22
        multiDexEnabled true

        compileOptions {
            sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
            targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles 'proguard-android.txt', 'proguard-project.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'
    compile 'com.google.guava:guava:18.0'
    compile files('libs/achartengine-1.1.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/commons-codec.jar')
    compile files('libs/commons-io-2.4.jar')
    compile files('libs/commons-net-3.3.jar')
    compile files('libs/dropbox-android-sdk-1.6.jar')
    compile files('libs/httpmime-4.0.3.jar')
    compile files('libs/iSpeech-SDK-1.4.2.jar')
    compile files('libs/json_simple-1.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/PayPal_MPL.jar')
    compile files('libs/sqlcipher.jar')
}
```

The gradle file after upgrade to API 23:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.3'
    compileOptions.encoding = 'windows-1251'

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    }
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.soft.StudyNJoy"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
        multiDexEnabled true

        compileOptions {
            sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
            targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles 'proguard-android.txt', 'proguard-project.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.4'
    compile 'com.google.guava:guava:18.0'
    compile files('libs/achartengine-1.1.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/commons-codec.jar')
    compile files('libs/commons-io-2.4.jar')
    compile files('libs/commons-net-3.3.jar')
    compile files('libs/dropbox-android-sdk-1.6.jar')
    compile files('libs/httpmime-4.0.3.jar')
    compile files('libs/iSpeech-SDK-1.4.2.jar')
    compile files('libs/json_simple-1.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/PayPal_MPL.jar')
    compile files('libs/sqlcipher.jar')
}
```

All the necessary permissions are in the manifest file - nothing has changed during upgrade from API 22 to API 23.
Has anyone an idea what could be wrong? 
Thanks in advance, kind regards
Gerhard

Comment: For API 23 there is a new Permission model. Have you asked for the permissions from the user? More details here: https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Comment: No, I didn't do any changes on the source code (except the gradle), I haven't asked explicitly for permission. So this might be the reason for the broken functionality. Thanks!

Comment: That's the expected behavior, it's not broken, until you ask permission for the user, you will only get empty/null responses

Answer (score 0):

In API 23 there is two kind of permissions, normal - that will be granted automatically if you add it to manifest, and dangerous - that should be granted by user via UI. ACCOUNT_MANAGER - is second kind of permissions. 
You need to request the permission method in this case first - https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Answer (score 0):

You have to get Runtime permission for API 23.

[**Have on Android official sample**](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html)

Comment: @ Sohail: my vote is not publicly displayed because i do not yet have a reputation >15. :-(